# Merging 2 database with complete different table structures

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress

I have an old website that was built to manage a large amount of users and data. This site is not a Wordpress site and I would like to transfer this sites data (users, properties and more) to a Wordpress site (database). All i would like to find out is if it is possible to accomplish this and if so what would be the best way of doing so.

At first i was thinking of manually re assigning database tables data to the Wordpress structure but would like to avoid it if possible because of the risk and time involved.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I don't know what your database structure is like, but it's extremely unlikely that you can just copy the data across. Usually a database migration takes quite a bit of time and effort. This question is a bit broad, and not possible to answer without finding out what your database structure looks like

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What is was thinking of doing is find a way to maybe match data columns in a table to that of a Wordpress structured table. For example using the data from DataTableOld "Name" and merging it with DataTableNew "Name2". Basically a way of telling what columns from the Old database matches the columns on the new database (Wordpress based database). Hope that makes more sense

Comment: Welcome, you will find you receive much better replies you phrase your question correctly and let us know what you have tried so far.. Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: If the databases are completely different, you'll need to perform the transformation yourself, or hire someone to do it for you (not cheap). This will require quite a bit of effort on your part (and time), or the help of some professional services. I'm afraid the help of an intern or other cheap resource won't be able to help much with this task.